# BASH: sorting an associative array with their keys

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

So I am quite struggling with arrays in shell scripting, especially dealing with sorting the key values. Here's what I have

```
declare -A array
Array[0]=(0)
Array[1]=(4)
Array[2]=(6)
Array[3]=(1)
```

So in each array we have (0,4,6,1), if we sort them to the largest to the smallest, it would be (6,4,1,0). Now, I wonder if I could sort the key of the value, and put them in a new array like this(sort of like ranking them):

```
newArray[0]=(2) # 2 which was the key for 6
newArray[1]=(1) # 1 which was the key for 4
newArray[2]=(3) # 3 which was the key for 1
newArray[3]=(0) # 0 which was the key for 0
```

I've tried some solutions but they are so much hard coded and not working for some situations. Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: SO posting guidelines expect you to show your effort (research, code) so consider updating the question with some of the `solutions` you've tried along with the (wrong) output generated by said code

Comment: fwiw, `Array[0]=(0)` is an invalid assignment (`bash` does not allow arrays of arrays); I'm guessing what you intend is `Array[0]=0`; also, if you only intend to use numeric keys/indexes then you don't need an associative array and, in this case, can more easily initialize the array with `unset Array; Array=(0 4 6 1)`

Comment: Is this an academic exercise? Because in real program for me `newArray` would be useless, in real life you would just sort the original array.

Comment: also, `bash` variable names are case sensisitive so this `declare -A array` and `Array[0]=0` are referencing two different variables `array` (lowercase `a`) and `Array` (uppercase `A`)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a tuple of index+value.
2. Sort over value.
3. Remove values.
4. Read into an array.

```
array=(0 4 6 1)

tmp=$(
   # for every index in the array
   for ((i = 0; i < ${#array[@]}; ++i)); do
       # output the index, space, an array value on every line
       echo "$i ${array[i]}"
   done |
   # sort lines using Key as second column Numeric Reverse
   sort -k2nr |
   # using space as Delimiter, extract first Field from each line
   cut -d' ' -f1
)
# Load tmp into an array separated by newlines.
readarray -t newArray <<<"$tmp"
# output
declare -p newArray
```

outputs:

```
declare -a newArray=([0]="2" [1]="1" [2]="3" [3]="0")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm a beginner to bash, so I don't think I understand I 'echo' store values to the array (and it also prints out things in terminal), could we use '+=' sort of things instead of echoing??

Comment: `and it also prints out things in terminal` when you `echo stuff` it shows on your terminal. When you `echo stuff | command` the output goes to `command`. In this case the whole output of a for loop goes to command. You can put any construct. `could we use '+=' sort of things instead of echoing?` I do not know how would you use it, `+=` does not sort anything, the command `sort` sorts lines inputted to it, i.e. `( echo 2; echo 1; ) | sort` would sort.